# Update every doctrine query before it is sent to the database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

We are running a huge platform that has a single database for multiple frontends. Now we are about to try to identify our slow queries and get an better idea of from what page our traffic comes from.

I had the idea to inject the page name as a comment in every sql query to be able to see it when looking at the database using `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

[image]

At the end it should look like this: `/*PAGE NAME*/ SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

If I do this in sequel pro it seems that the comment gets listed then:

[image]

How can I update every doctrine query using a listener/subscriber to inject a custom comment?

Comment: Doctrine listener/subscriber/filters will not support this.  All I can suggest is  extending the Doctrine connection object and then maybe find a spot before the generated sql is sent to the database server.  But I don't think your approach is a good one.  Database servers have many tools profiling tools for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doctrine DBAL allows you to define your own Connection class.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        wrapper_class: App\DBAL\MyConnectionWrapper
```

You could implement a child class of `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` and override `executeQuery()` according to your needs.

```
class MyConnectionWrapper extends Connection
{
  public function executeQuery($sql, array $params = [], $types = [], ?QueryCacheProfile $qcp = null)
  {
    $sql = '/*PAGE NAME*/ '.$sql;
    return parent::executeQuery($sql, $params, $types, $qcp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please check this [Symfony documentation : Doctrine Event Listeners and Subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) To understand the following code

Here is how i did it for each update, in order to update the update time:

```
    <?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Exception;
use Stringable;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use function is_object;

class DatabaseActivitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;
    /**
     * @var null|User
     */
    private ?User $user;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->user = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::prePersist,
            Events::preUpdate,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Initiate the name of the user creating the object with "LastName FirstName (id)"
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $object = $args->getObject();
        if ($object instanceof AbstractEntity && $this->getUser() instanceof User) {
            $object->setCreateUser($this->getUser()->getLastName() . ' ' . $this->getuser()->getLastName() . ' (' . $this->getuser()->getId() . ')');
            $object->setCreateDate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string|Stringable|UserInterface|null|User
     */
    private function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->user instanceof User){
            return $this->user;
        }
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        if (null === $token) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
            return null;
        }
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $object = $args->getObject();
        if ($object instanceof AbstractEntity && $this->getUser() instanceof User) {
            $object->setUpdateUser($this->getuser()->getLastName() . ' ' . $this->getuser()->getLastName() . ' (' . $this->getuser()->getId() . ')');
            $object->setUpdateDate();
        }
    }
}
```

And add in service.yaml:

```
    App\EventListener\DatabaseActivitySubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber' }
```

Comment: Thanks four your reply. But I can't see you injecting/modifying any sql query in your code? :-)

Comment: All my entities extends AbstractEntity. So  when i update on of them, i set updateUser and updateDate in preupdate function. This change is automatically converted into dql/sql

Comment: Jep, but the question is about how to extend **every** query before it is sent, not about receiving updates when entities change :-)